# android why i cannot change the project theme to noactionbar

Tags: android, themes

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>
```

My project minimun sdk is API16. I am following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMO8EVkhJO8 setting the theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. If i run the app, null exception shows up... What should i do. Any problem with the gradle file?

```
04-23 15:03:57.589    2045-2045/com.it.fyp.tab E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.it.fyp.tab/com.it.fyp.tab.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.it.fyp.tab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.it.fyp.tab" >


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] planets = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer Opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        if (toolbar != null){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }else{
            Log.i("NULL TOOLBAR", "YES");
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        selectItem(position);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(planets[position]);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your AndroidManifest.xml in your post.

Comment: @cygery................

Comment: Please include your MainActivity code.

Comment: have you added AppCompat library?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' this in gradle file? @PiotrGolinski

Comment: going to create the navigation drawer

Comment: Which line is line 61?

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); @cygery

Comment: I remove the getSupportActionBar then work Thanks!! @cygery

Answer (score 0):

Create a theme like below-

```
<style name="myAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">True</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">False</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: just clean your project after adding this theme and use it in manifest, it works

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to handle customizing themes with a parent is to declare the theme directly in your Manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Then in your separate style XML have that theme as a parent:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
   <item name=..../>
    ....
</style>
```

Then in your specific activity snippet in your Manifest set the theme to your new theme:

```
<activity>
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</activity>
```